# Converting Map<String, Object> to json

Tags: java, json, jsp, gson

I have a map called responseObj

```
Map<String, object> responseObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I have added some value in the responseObj like this -

```
responseObj.put("canApprove", true); //1
responseObj.put("approvers", userList);
```

The `userList` is a list or users -

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

The user Object from the User class -

```
class User {
 private int userId;
 private int roleId;
}
```

Now I have some questions -

1. Is it possible to convert the `responseObj` to a json so that `"canApprove"` and `"approvers"` become key of json (see the code snippent below) and how can I make it?

   ```
   {
    "canApprove" : true,
    "approver": [
   {
     "userId": 309,
     "roleId": 2009
   },
   {
     "userId": 3008,
     "roleId": 2009
   },
   ```

   ]
       }
2. If I convert it into a json and get the response from jsp can I able get the appropriate boolean in jsp where the `"canApprove"` refers an `Object` in the `responseObj`?
3. Can I persist the `"userId" and "roleId"` to JSON from `User` Class?

Comment: What did you try? As for no.1: I don't know gson but I assume it might just work. Other JSON libs have JSONObject classes that basically are maps and JSONArray classes that basically are lists, so it should not be that complicated. As for no.2: I don't quite get your question but since the JS in JSON stands for JavaScript you'd just use the JSON result on your page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static class User
{
    public User(int userId, int roleId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
    private int userId;
    private int roleId;
    public int getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }
    public int getRoleId()
    {
        return roleId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public void setRoleId(int roleId)
    {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
}
```

Test :

```
Map<String, Object> responseObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
userList.add(new User(1, 1));
userList.add(new User(2, 2));
responseObj.put("canApprove", true); //1
responseObj.put("approvers", userList);

System.out.println(new JSONObject(responseObj));
```

Prints :

```
{"approvers":[{"userId":1,"roleId":1},{"userId":2,"roleId":2}],"canApprove":true}
```

[(formatted)](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ac5e0cd66f61bd9b0167ec85368ea895)

Comment: which library are you using for this example?

Comment: Please mention the library you are using for JSONObject.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use JSONObject to parse the map to JSON.

The maven dependency is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
```

later create a new JSON object and pass the map

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseObj);
```

and return the object to this web client.

Answer (score 1):

```
new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(responseObj);
```

Comment: Does this method satisfy the question 3(I have add the question 3 later). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes. You will be surprised how well Gson works. At least i was,  really intuitive

Answer (score 0):

You can use some json serialization libraries to do this work for you, like [fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) or [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

1.Import the dependency jars into your project, add a `<dependency>` node into you pom.xml if you are using maven, or simply drop the jar in you project's library folder

2.`String jsonString = JSON.toJSONString(responseObj);` (using fastjson)